# wordpress functions.php not loading javascript files

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'am trying to include all my css and JS files of a theme using functions.php

Folowing is what i have done so far

```
 <?php

    function blogroom() {

        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('loaders',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/loaders.css/loaders.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('iconsmind',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/iconsmind/iconsmind.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('hamburgers',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/hamburgers/dist/hamburgers.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome-css',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-style',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-style',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/custom.css');
        wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        wp_register_script( 'imageloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array( 'bootstrap-js' ) );
        wp_register_script( 'tweenmax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js', array('imageloaded') );
        wp_register_script( 'scroll-to-plugin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/gsap/src/minified/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js', array('tweenmax') );
        wp_register_script( 'customToEase', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/CustomEase.min.js', array('scroll-to-plugin') );
        wp_register_script( 'configJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/config.js', array('customToEase') );
        wp_register_script( 'zanimation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/zanimation.js', array('configJs') );
        wp_register_script( 'corejs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/core.js', array('zanimation') );
        wp_register_script( 'mainjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array('corejs') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mainjs' );    
     }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blogroom' );


?>
```

Here, this only loads my CSS file and not my js files. not a single javascript file is loaded.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works

Comment: [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) instead of [wp_register_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/).....

Answer (score 1):

You are only registering the scripts without enqueuing them.

Do for each script the same as you did for main.js, meaning for each registered script, enqueue it

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'your registered script name' );
```

Also make sure you have wp_head() and wp_footer() in your theme header and, respectively the footer.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that `wp_register_script` is not necessary, unless you're going to `localize_scripts` - so that can be skipped, and just do the `wp_enqueue_script`....  otherwise, just adding `wp_enqueue_scripts` makes the functions file that much longer / more verbose / difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be due to a misunderstanding of [wp_register_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) vs [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/).

`wp_register_script` only tells WP that there is a script at the given location, and gives it a "handle" to be used for other purposes.
`wp_enqueue_scripts` tells WP to *use* the script.  And, there's two formats - the "long" format is like `wp_register_script`, so you can tell WP where the script is, AND to load it, all in one command.

The code below will work - I've changed your `wp_register_script` calls to `wp_enqueue_script`:

```
function blogroom() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('loaders',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/loaders.css/loaders.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('iconsmind',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/iconsmind/iconsmind.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('hamburgers',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/hamburgers/dist/hamburgers.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome-css',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('theme-style',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('theme-style',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/custom.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'imageloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array( 'bootstrap-js' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tweenmax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js', array('imageloaded') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scroll-to-plugin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/gsap/src/minified/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js', array('tweenmax') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customToEase', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/CustomEase.min.js', array('scroll-to-plugin') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'configJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/config.js', array('customToEase') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'zanimation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/zanimation.js', array('configJs') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'corejs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/core.js', array('zanimation') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mainjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array('corejs') );  
 }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blogroom' );
```

Typically, you would only use `wp_register_script` in a few scenarios - here's two common ones:
1. You want to `localize_script` using [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) (this permits you to output javascript variables from your PHP that would be considered "related" to the registered script)
2. You want to register the script because you may or may NOT output the scripts later (this is particularly useful when authoring a shortcode, you can register the script, set a "flag" if the shortcode is rendered, and the footer can output the scripts only if the flag is set).   This method can be seen in this article: [How to load JavaScript like a WordPress Master](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)